# How can i add a tabulator character to my query

Tags: sql, oracle, output-formatting

I wrote 3 queries:

```
   select column1 from table_name1 where -- conditions) 
   ||' TEXT2: '|| (select column2 from table_name2 where  -- conditions) 
   ||' TEXT3: '|| (select column3 from table_name3 where  -- conditions)
```

This seems to work. Here is the output:

```
column1 'TEXT2:' column2 'TEXT3:' column3
```

I tried to use `CHR(09)`, but I think I can't use it properly or it's not working with our system - *the 3 select statements are part of an internal query in our system in EAS (-enterprise application software)* - I tried it with this format `query1||CHR(09)||query2` but it doesn't put the `tab` into the output.

Expected output in rows:

```
'TEXT1:' column1||tab character||'TEXT2:' column2||tab character||'TEXT3:' column3
```

Maybe i should try to use `lpad(' ',8)` to put whitespace into it ?

**How can i achieve the expected output ?**

Comment: Show how you used `CHR(9)`

Comment: What is an IS? What is Orcle DBD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the  type of all 3 columns is text(`VARCHAR2/CHAR`) , you may first do a `UNION ALL` and then apply `LISTAGG` with `CHR(9)` as delimiter.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(text 
               || ': ' 
               || col, CHR(9)) 
         within GROUP( ORDER BY text ) 
FROM   (SELECT column1 AS col, 
               'TEXT1' AS text 
        FROM   table_name1 --where conditions 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT column2 AS col, 
               'TEXT2' AS text 
        FROM   table_name2 --where conditions 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT column3 AS col, 
               'TEXT3' AS text 
        FROM   table_name3 --where conditions    
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this:

((select ' TEXT1: '||column1 from table_name1 where conditions) ||CHR(09)||' TEXT2: '|| (select column2 from table_name2 where conditions) ||'CHR(09)||'TEXT3: '|| (select column3 from table_name3 where conditions))